# File upload via Swagger UI

Tags: php, restler

Is there a way to demonstrate file uploads using Restler via Swagger UI?

I like to be able to do something like:

```
function post() {
   return $_FILES;    
}
```

And expect to see the $_FILES array content displayed as a result of swagger ajax call.

Is there any combination of `@param` annotations that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger UI does not support that feature yet, but that might change in the future